# How to generate a text into an png without spacing (top and bottom)

Tags: php, jquery, html, canvas, png

I am trying to write a php function to convert text (via **imagettftext**) into an image (**png**) cropped from the top to the bottom of the letters.

I've tried with **GD** (php) and **html2canvas** (javascript)

But the generated image has always a spacing around the text. The text is contained in a  for the height and line-height...

Comment: If you showed what you've tried so far, with GD and html2canvas, it would be easier to help you. It might be that a small change to your code leads to the result you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
 <?php
    header ("Content-type: image/png");
    $text='CONVERT ME TO AN IMAGE';
    $string = $text;                                            
    $font   = 3;
    $width  = ImageFontWidth($font) * strlen($string); // minimum width required to hold the font
    $height = ImageFontHeight($font);

    $im = @imagecreate ($width,$height);
    $background_color = imagecolorallocate ($im, 255, 255, 255); //white background
    $text_color = imagecolorallocate ($im, 0, 0,0);//black text
    imagestring ($im, $font, 0, 0,  $string, $text_color);
    echo imagepng ($im);
    ?>
```

Comment: Thank you, but the generated image has padding around the text. how to generate an png form a text without padding around the text?

Comment: What do you mean by there is padding? Its the minimum width and height required to display the text.

Comment: Yes, but i need to generate a text and get its size (width and height) in centimeter. So i need to adjust the image or text cropped from top to bottom and left to right. Otherwise the size returned is not exact. Maybe you know an other solution? Thanks for help

Comment: Still didn't understand what you need. Can you explain with an example?

Comment: Do you understand with the example?